# random perlinNoise in AS3 (for water ripple effect)

Tags: actionscript-3, perlin-noise

when using DisplacementMapFilter along with perlinNoise i can get very realistic water effect
like the one presensted [here](http://rhuno.com/flashblog/2010/04/29/realistic-water-effect/)

problem is it works nicely only with small pictures, using it with big pictures (like 1024x768 pix) is too heavy, specially on mobile devices and

that's why i was hoping to find a away to apply this effect only on random parts of the picture (in loop, each time other random part of the picture is effected)

is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think only applying the effect on random parts or partially each frame will look strange (I think you will see the "cheating").

Have you tried generating a displacement map image with half the resolution of the picture and then scale it up (with smoothing turned on) before using it as a displacement map? Maybe the lower resolution won't be *that* noticeable?

Comment: sound like a good idea but i'm not familiar with scaling images in AS3, i'll try to google it but if you have a reference that would be great!

Comment: Have a look at the [BitmapData.draw()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()) method. With that method you can draw a BitmapData into another BitmapData with a scaling factor.

Comment: tnx! i'll give it a try
..i wish there was an easy way to do ripple effect for iOS with AS3 (AIR)..from what I see right now every one is using the same rippler class (http://www.derschmale.com/2008/08/03/water-ripples-revisited-as3-only-version/) which looks great on PC but has not so great performance on iPad..